# What is this bitwise shift left doing?

Tags: c, floating-point, binary

I am going over someone else's code written a few years ago which is pretty badly documented. At one point there is the following code snippet:

```
#define BINARYPOINT 16
....
float x;
int y;
int z;
....
....
//x has new values now
y = (int) (x*(1<<BINARYPOINT));
z = arctan2(y);
x = z;
```

In the code y is being explicitly used to compute the arctan of it, function arctan takes an int and gives the arctan of it which is another int. Now my trouble is here, I don't see how computing the arctan of `x*(1<<BINARYPOINT)` will give me the arctan of x?

Can anybody please explain what is going on here?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: is this someone's twisted idea of doing fixed-point math with floats??

Comment: @nneonneo, I don't know that it's that twisted, but that is what it appears to be.

Comment: It's twisted because there's no reason to store fixed point values in `float`...

Comment: Also, `arctan2` takes two arguments `y, x` in every implementation that I've seen. Maybe this `arctan2` operates on fixed-point `y,x` pairs stored in integers?

Comment: @neonneo, well, if you have the value as a `float` for some reason, but you have a function (like the OP's) that takes a fixed-point value, what other choice do you have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code is doing [Binary Scaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_scaling).  The floating point number is converted to an integer representation with a B16 binary scale, and then the function `arctan2` is called. This is a routine that takes an integer argument and knows that it is using a B16 scale factor. It's not the standard `atan` call that takes a `double` argument.

Note that the name of the function, `arctan2`, makes it look like it's intended to be the two argument version of the arctan, so you should check into that and make sure you're making the right call.

Comment: Yeah it's a special arctan implemented using CORDIC so conversion to  fixed point  makes sense.